# If Statement "Your Code Will Never Be Executed"

Tags: c++

The if else at the bottom will not work; it says that pets do not really exist.

```
void checkIn ()
{

    int roomNum = 0;
    int party = 0;
    char pets;
    char smoke;

    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to Shrek's Swamp Inn" << endl << endl;

    cout << "How many people are In your party? " << endl;
    cin >> party;

    cout << "Do you have pets? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> pets;

    switch (pets)
    {
        case 'Y' : case 'y':
            cout << "GTLO" << endl;
            break;
        case 'N' : case 'n':
            cout << "cool cool" << endl;
            break;
        default :
            cout << "User error" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Do you want a smoke room? (Y/N) " << endl;
    cin >> smoke;

    switch (smoke)
    {
        case 'Y' : case 'y':
            cout << "GTLO" << endl;
            break;
        case 'N' : case 'n':
            cout << "cool cool" << endl;
            break;
        default :
            cout << "User error" << endl;
    }

    if((pets == 'Y' || 'y') && (smoke == 'Y' || 'y')){
        roomNum = rand() % 4 + 1;
        cout << "Your room is " << roomNum << "S" << endl;
    }
    else if((pets == 'Y' || 'y') && (smoke == 'n' || 'N')){
        roomNum = rand() % 8 + 5;

        cout << "Your room is " << roomNum << "P" << endl;
    }
    else if((pets == 'n' || 'N') && (smoke == 'n' || 'N'));{
        roomNum = rand() % 15 + 9;

        cout << "Your room is " << roomNum << "R" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 8):

You should change the if condition

```
(pets == 'Y' || 'y')
```

to

```
(pets == 'Y' || pets == 'y')
```

Otherwise, `'y'` (as a non-zero value) will always be evaluated as `true` for if condition, then `(pets == 'Y' || 'y')` will be always `true` too.

And it's the same for all other if conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to songyuanyao's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36159457/1503646), you have another syntax error

```
else if((pets == 'n' || 'N') && (smoke == 'n' || 'N'));{
```

Note the semicolon `;` towards the end of the statement, you need to remove this